# RabbitMQ consume messages with some delay

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I'm using rabbitmq producer and consumer with nodejs. If I push 1000 messages in a sec to a queue , I dont want to consume it all at once. I want to consume 10 messages at one sec and so on. How to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You should familiarize yourself with how AMQP and RabbitMQ works, especially by doing the [tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html).

[Tutorial two](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html) introduces the concept of `prefetch` (also referred to as `QoS`) which will limit the number of un-acknowledged messages sent to a consumer.

Comment: Whomever downvoted this - using `prefetch` and a timer within their application is one way to solve this. I'm not going to code it for them.